# Spyder profiler times don't add up (totalTime =/= localTime + sub-function totalTime)

Tags: python, spyder

[image]

So the total time of optimizeVoxels = 1.86 min * 60sec/min = 111 seconds.

However, this doesn't match the profiler results from the local time and sub-functions.
localTime(optimizeVoxels) = 24.93 ms = 0.024 sec

subFunction total times = 28.26+20.40+13.67+12.46+4.63+0.43146+0.23991+0.07237+0.00757+0.00191 = 80.173 seconds, and even if we add 0.024 to this, it's still just 80.197.

The gap between 80.197 and 111 seconds is extremely large from my perspective -- any ideas what the discrepancy could be here?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) To our understand the meaning of those results, please see [this page](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/profiler.html#interpreting-the-results) and [this video](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/working-with-spyder.html#optimizing-your-code).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I checked [interpreting](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/profiler.html?highlight=profiler#interpreting-the-results) and [optimizing](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/videos/working-with-spyder.html?highlight=optimizing), and still don't understand. Is there another reference?

Comment: Nop, sorry, we don't have more docs about it.